# MySql automatic restart after memory runs full

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

we're using MySql on CloudSql for quite some time now.
Obviously, we started with Mysql 5 but after a long wait and the final release of Mysql8 we decided to upgrade our database server.
As the title promotes, we now see a strange behavior of our memory utilization.
As you can see here it constantly fills up until server max resources are reached and then restarts and start filling up again.
[image]

I mean there could be an issue with one of our services but before the upgrade our memory consumption looked like this:
[image]
So you can see, memory consumption was more or less constant.

Furthermore, we increased resources when we upgraded to mysql8 and switched from db-n1-standard-1 to db-n1-standard-2, to have more available resources when data grows up.

Does anyone knows this behavior? Is there a change in Mysql5 to 8? I didn't find any information about it. Just found some notes that it's normal that Mysql takes as much memory as it can get. But I'm still wondering why it didn't on Mysql5.

Some more details on the configuration:

- We're using read replica for HA
- Binarylogs activated
- Slow Query log enabled with FILE output.

Everything else is default CloudSql Configuration.

Any help is much appreciated.

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems that MySQL 8 is consuming more memory than MySQL 5. As shown in some tests performed by the author of the article [MySQL 8 and MySQL 5.7 Memory Consumption on Small Devices](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/08/14/mysql-8-and-mysql-5-7-memory-consumption-on-small-devices/)
, the memory used by the version 8 in same VM settings is considerably higher than on versions 5, including both resident and virtual memories - even though these are tests in small VMs, it's a good indication that this occurs in bigger configurations as well.

So, yes, it seems that, as you mentioned, it's normal that Mysql takes as much memory as it can get, but that indeed, MySQL 8 is consuming more memory than the 5 one.

Comment: sry for the late reply... was a little busy the last days...
It's ok that mysql 8 uses more memory but why is the memory that fluttering?
Each time it clears the memory all our clients looses their connection....